# Why was Sgt. Wu eating couch stuffing?

Tags: grimm

At the end of the episode ["Island of Dreams"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2200281/) [Sgt. Wu](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0250474/) is recovering

> from eating a love potion cookie intended for someone else

and he is seen pulling open one of his couch cushions and eating the contents.  What is he eating and why?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. Figured it might relate to the idea that he was still recovering and so hungry that he deliriously ate the stuffing thinking it was food, but it definitely made me wonder if there was more to it.

Comment: @MatthewFrederick I had the same thought, but it's Grimm, so you really don't know...

Comment: At the start of episode 16 he's snacking on paperclips, so it's not just post-drug delerium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the following episode [*Love Sick*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2222231/)

> The antidote seemed to only cure Sgt Wu's physical ailments, not the mental one imparted by the cookie (eating random objects).  An additional antidote (this one inhaled), seemed to cure Sgt Wu.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two main possibilities:

- > He's a Wesen that's been able to control himself pretty well so far.  Nick can only see them when they lose control or shift intentionally.
- > Rosalie messed up when she made the cure for Sgt. Wu, and that's an unintentional side effect.

Given the timing, I think the second one is more likely.